# Way to change floating button icon when pressed

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to change the floating button's icon when pressed?
Code:

```
var musicButton = new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: (){
      if(playerState == PlayerState.playing) {
        //setState(() => child = new Icon(Icons.pause));
        setState((){
          child: new Icon(Icons.play_arrow);
        });
        pause();
      } else if (playerState == PlayerState.paused){
        setState((){
          child: new Icon(Icons.pause);
        });
        play();
      }
    },
    tooltip: 'Play Music',
    child: new Icon(Icons.pause));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use a state variable to switch between icons.

Example:

```
bool playing = false;
```

then

```
var musicButton = new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: (){
      if(playerState == PlayerState.playing) {
        setState((){
          playing = false;
        });
        pause();
      } else if (playerState == PlayerState.paused){
        setState((){
          playing = true;
        });
        play();
      }
    },
    tooltip: 'Play Music',
    child: playing?new Icon(Icons.pause):new Icon(Icons.play_arrow));
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumeration also *enum* used to define named constant values.

```
enum Gender {Male,Female,} // enum definition globally
Gender selectedGender;    // enum declaration

onPress: () {
             setState(() {
             selectedGender = Gender.Male;
              });
            },
```

Now you can use selectedGender Dart Conditional Operators ( ? : ) anywhere in your code.